# What is the correct way to sample a 16-bit height map in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, sampling

I have a heightmap which is made of 16-bit signed values, I was just wondering what the correct way to sample them from the shader is. So far I'm using the GL_R16 format, which I think stores the image as unsigned ints, but when sampled returns a float, which I assume is normalised to 0 - 1. Is there an option also to sample the texture as an int as stored in the texture instead of as a float?

When I upload the texture I do:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, 10800, 10800, 0, GL_R16, GL_SHORT, buffer.data());
```

And in my shader I sample it like:

```
float colour = texture2D(heightmap, texCoords).r;
outFragColour = vec4(colour, colour, colour, 1);
```

It seems to be sampling only black (ie., 0);

Also, does this preserve negative values of the heightmap? This is all very confusing.

EDIT: I just realised I get an INVALID_ENUM error from OpenGL when calling:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, 10800, 10800, 0, GL_R16, GL_SHORT, buffer.data());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Texture format:

- `GL_R16` maps [0, 65535] interval to [0, 1]. It cannot natively represent negative values, though of course you can adjust the value after you sampled yourself.
- `GL_R16_SNORM` will map the [-32767, 32767] range to [-1, 1] when sampling, so you can store negative values natively.
- `GL_R16I` does no mapping. It stores the values [-32768, 32767] and returns them exactly when sampled. However, this texture format *does not support interpolation*, so the only minification/magnification filters you can specify are `GL_NEAREST` and `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`. You must use the integer sampler types in the shader (like `isampler2D`) and the sampling functions will return the data in `ivec4`.
- `GL_R16UI` is the same as `GL_R16I` but for unsigned data in the [0, 65535] range. The corresponding sampler type is `usampler2D` and the sampling functions return the data in `uvec4`.
- `GL_R16F` is the half-float format. It is a good alternative to all the above, as it has the benefits of normal floating points data if you can tolerate its lower precision.

#### As for your code:

It's unclear why you get only black. If all the values in your `data` are small, then it is possible that they are simply rounded to zero when converted to the on-screen 8-bit format, so you see all black.

Make sure that you don't get any errors (e.g. your texture is quite large, does OpenGL has enough memory to create this texture?).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I realised that I get an INVALID_ENUM error when calling glTexImage(). I'm trying to figure out whether it's the GL_R16 or the GL_SHORT.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: ah, you're right. I've missed that. It should be internalFormat=GL_R16, format=GL_RED, type=GL_SHORT.

Comment: I see. So the internal format as GL_R16 specifies that it's 16 bit (ie. each texel/pixel is 16 bits large, and the format GL_RED specifies... umm that the value stored there is retrieved by sampling .r in the shader? If the format were GL_RG instead of GL_RED and I sampled .r in the shader, would it still sample the 16 bit value? Sorry, this is confusing.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: `glTexImage` unpacks the data from the memory you hand to it and stores it in the texture.`format` and `type` describe how the data is read from your memory. `internalFormat` describes how the data is stored on the GPU side. I'm not sure what happens if the two don't match, and I cannot currently find the relevant part of the spec. You simply shouldn't do that, I think.